# How to unbind a namespaced event on an element that has multiple events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an event listener that fires when the user clicks outside the respective element.

My problem is that the unbind function clears *all* instances of this event -- not just the namespaced event.

How can I unbind a namespaced event when there are multiple events bound to the same element?

---

```
     _ myModal _ _ _ _ _
    |                   |
    |   dropdown        |
    |                   |
    |                   |
    |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|

    registerOutsideClickHandler('.myModal', closeModal);
    registerOutsideClickHandler('.myDropdown', closeDropdown);

    function registerOutsideClickHandler (container, callback) {

        let eventNamespace = 'click' + container;

        return $('body').on(eventNamespace, function(evt) {

            if ( !$(evt.target).parents(container).length ) {

                callback(evt);
                //TODO this is broken - unbinds ALL the click events on $('body')
                $('body').off(eventNamespace);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Three caveats:**

1. the handler is an anonymous function
2. the events all share a common element, $('body');
3. there are often multiple handlers active at once, but each has a unique namespace

**Example:**

The user registers an event listener by opening the modal (`click.myModal`). Then, the user registers a second event listener by opening a dropdown inside of the modal (`click.myDropdown`).

If the user clicks outside of the dropdown but still inside the modal, the dropdown will close. This is expected. However, the unbind function has also removed the first event listener, `click.myModal`. After clicking outside the dropdown to close the dropdown, clicking outside the modal will not close the modal. This is not expected.

Thanks for any insight you can offer.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/k4sd06cj/) ?

Comment: Me neither: https://jsfiddle.net/4bxdfkaf/

Comment: You're right! The code works OK.